# Optionally pass argument to subprocess in python

Tags: python, subprocess, command-line-arguments

In my script I call an executable with optional command line argument (if passed, this argument switches on a function in the executable, which is off by default). I want to control this option directly from argument of the script itself. Write now I do:

```
import subprocess
option = False
if option:
    check = subprocess.Popen(['executable', '--option'])
else:
    check = subprocess.Popen(['executable'])
```

I tried to find a more compact way:

```
import subprocess
option = False
check = subprocess.Popen(['executable', '--option' if option else ''])
```

But this raises error "Unknown option" in the exactable itself.

And this raises error in python:

```
import subprocess
option = False
check = subprocess.Popen(['executable', '--option' if option else None])
```

So, my question: is there a way to pass an optional argument to subprocess in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using list slicing:

```
>>> ['executable', '--option'][:1 + False]
['executable']
>>> ['executable', '--option'][:1 + True]
['executable', '--option']

>>> False == 0
True
>>> True == 1
True
```

---

```
check = subprocess.Popen(['executable', '--option'][:1 + option])
```

**UPDATE**
Alternative

You can also use `list` * `bool`:

```
>>> ['a'] * True
['a']
>>> ['a'] * False
[]
```

Using this, you can combine multiple options:

```
check = subprocess.Popen(['executable'] +
                         ['-option1'] * option1 +
                         ['-option2'] * option2)
```

Comment: And if there are several such options (e.g. executable [--option1] [--option2] ...)?

Comment: @Roman, Assuming `option` variable is a boolean object, you can use alternative `list` * `bool`: `subprocess.Popen(['executable'] + ['-option1'] * option1 + ['-option2'] * option2)`

Answer (score 4):

An alternative that's IMO more readable than the current suggestion is using list unpacking:

```
*(['--opt=val'] if opt else [])
```

And with your example:

```py
check = subprocess.Popen([
    'executable',
    *(['--option'] if option else [])
])
```